# Is NSPasteboard thread-safe?

Tags: cocoa, multithreading

Is it safe to write data to an NSPasteboard object from a background thread?  I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere.  I think the assumption is that the data will be written to the pasteboard before the drag begins.

Background:
I have an application that is fetching data from Evernote.  When the application first loads, it gets the meta data for each note, but not the note content.  The note stubs are then listed in an outline view.  When the user starts to drag a note, the notes are passed to the background thread that handles getting the note content from Evernote.  Having the main thread block until the data is gotten results in a significant delay and a poor user experience, so I have the  `[outlineView:writeItems:toPasteboard:]` function return `YES` while the background thread processes the data and invokes the main thread to write the data to the pasteboard object.  If the note content gets transferred before the user drops the note somewhere, everything works perfectly.  If the user drops the note somewhere before the data has been processed... well, everything blocks forever.  Is it safe to just have the background thread write the data to the pasteboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can promise the data to the pasteboard without actually having the data yet.

One way is to declare the type of the data on the pasteboard, passing yourself as the pasteboard's owner, and respond to [a `pasteboard:provideDataForType:` message](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/pasteboard:provideDataForType:) by providing the data (blocking, if necessary, until the data either arrives or fails to arrive). This means that you'll need to remember which objects were copied (by stashing them in an array, for example) so you can extract/generate the data from them when the promise comes due.

The other way, referenced in Harald Scheirich's answer, is to make your model objects conform to [the NSPasteboardWriting protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPasteboardWriting_Protocol/), ideally in a category (to separate interface-independent logic from Mac-specific logic). This is much cleaner than the old way, but requires Mac OS X 10.6 and later.

With NSPasteboardWriting, you'll implement promises by having the model objects' [`writingOptionsForType:pasteboard:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPasteboardWriting_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSPasteboardWriting/writingOptionsForType:pasteboard:) return [the `NSPasteboardWritingPromised` option](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPasteboardWriting_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPasteboardWritingPromised). Their  [`pasteboardPropertyListForType:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPasteboardWriting_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSPasteboardWriting/pasteboardPropertyListForType:) will return the data, or at least try to—as before, this method should block until the data either arrives or fails to arrive.

Oh, and to answer the question in the title (“Is NSPasteboard thread-safe?”): There's no specific answer in the [Thread Safety Summary](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html), but there is this general statement:

> … mutable objects are generally not thread-safe. To use mutable objects in a threaded application, the application must synchronize appropriately.

I would consider an NSPasteboard to be a mutable object, so no.

In practice, this isn't a problem: You typically only work with NSPasteboard in response to an action message (e.g., `copy:`), a drag, or a service invocation, and those all only happen on the main thread anyway. For them to happen on a secondary thread, you would have to explicitly send such messages yourself from code running on a secondary thread, in which case you are already doing something very wrong.

Comment: Thanks!  This application is being built against 10.5, so the NSPasteboardWriting protocol is out.  I'll try out the pasteboard:provideDataForType: method.  I think it won't be too difficult now.

Answer (score 0):

Conjecture:

I think your problem has nothing to do with threading but the fact that by returning `YES` you told the system that the data is ready. have you tried moving your data into a custom class supporting  `NSPasteboardWriting` and  `NSPasteboardReading`? this way the accessor to your data can block until the data is ready.

See the [Pasteboard Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbCustom.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008122-SW1)